# NS3 ./Waf - fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, c++, compiler-errors, ns-3, waf

Im using Ns3 and I need to embed python but im faving some issues.If I try to build the application it give the error ** Python.h: No such file or directory**.
I have already install python3.9-dev, the waf configuration that im using is the following :

```bash
./waf configure --disable-examples --disable-tests  --enable-modules='applications','core','internet','point-to-point','wifi','flow-monitor','spectrum' --enable-static -d optimized  --with-python=/usr/include/python3.9
```

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)